# How to convert a Cursor into SELECT queries?

Tags: t-sql, select, cursor

I am using SSRS 2008 and i have a stored proc which currently uses cursors to delete and add data, but even after I convert this to select queries, I am getting error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Here was the original Cursor which worked:

```
OPEN PARTS
FETCH PARTS INTO    @PART_NUM,
@PART_DESC
SET @PARTS_FETCH = @@FETCH_STATUS
WHILE @PARTS_FETCH = 0 BEGIN
SET @THE_DATE = dateadd("yy", -1, dateadd("m", -1, getdate()))
SET @END_DATE = DATEADD(ms, -5, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))

-- Get PL for part number 
Delete from @tbl_PL

Insert @tbl_PL 
SELECT FRUD.tblXref.product_code FROM FRUD.tblfieldOrderablePart INNER JOIN
FRUD.MAX_APPROVED ON FRUD.tblfieldOrderablePart.fop_no = FRUD.MAX_APPROVED.fop_no AND 
FRUD.tblfieldOrderablePart.fop_revision = FRUD.MAX_APPROVED.MaxOffop_revision INNER JOIN
FRUD.tblXref ON FRUD.MAX_APPROVED.fop_no = FRUD.tblXref.fop_no AND 
FRUD.MAX_APPROVED.MaxOffop_revision = FRUD.tblXref.fop_revision
WHERE (dbo.FORMAT_PART(FRUD.tblfieldOrderablePart.fop_no) = dbo.FORMAT_PART(@PART_NUM))
-- End Get PL

WHILE @THE_DATE <= @END_DATE BEGIN
SET @THE_DATE = DATEADD(ms, -5, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @THE_DATE) + 1, 0))
-- Get census using PL          
SELECT @ALL_TOTAL = SUM(TheSum) FROM (SELECT CAST(RELIABILITY.Census.Census AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TheSum, (CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(char, Period), 4) + '-' + RIGHT(Period, 2) + '-1', 102)) as ThePeriod
FROM RELIABILITY.Census
WHERE RELIABILITY.Census.PL In (Select distinct * FROM @tbl_PL)
AND (CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(char, Period), 4) + '-' + RIGHT(Period, 2) + '-1', 102) >=
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0)) AND (CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(char, Period), 4)
+ '-' + RIGHT(Period, 2) + '-1', 102) <= @THE_DATE)                         UNION ALL                           SELECT     CAST(Census AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TheSum, Period                           FROM         [MANUAL].SMARTSOLVE_CENSUS                         WHERE     (Period >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0) AND Period <= @THE_DATE) AND (PL In (Select distinct * FROM @tbl_PL)))A
```

And here is my conversion to Select:

```
DECLARE @THE_DATE datetime,
        @END_DATE datetime,
        @THE_GOAL decimal(18,2),
        @PART_NUM nvarchar(50),
        @UNCHANGED_PART_NUM nvarchar(50),
        @PART_DESC varchar(35),
        @PARTS_FETCH int,
        @NUM_FAILED int,
        @AVG_CENSUS decimal(18,2),
        @PL_VAR nvarchar(50),   
        @PL_FETCH int,
        @PL_TOTAL decimal(9,2),
        @ALL_TOTAL decimal(9,2)

--WHILE @PARTS_FETCH = 0 BEGIN
    SET @THE_DATE = dateadd("yy", -1, dateadd("m", -1, getdate()))
    SET @END_DATE = DATEADD(ms, -5, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))  
    --WHILE @THE_DATE <= @END_DATE BEGIN
SET @THE_DATE = DATEADD(ms, -5, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @THE_DATE) + 1, 0))
-- Get census using PL

SELECT @ALL_TOTAL = SUM(TheSum) FROM 
(SELECT CAST(RELIABILITY.Census.Census AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TheSum 
from RELIABILITY.Census
WHERE RELIABILITY.Census.PL In (Select distinct * FROM #tbl_PL) 
AND (CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(char, Period), 4) + '-' + RIGHT(Period, 2) + '-1', 102) >=  
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0)) AND (CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(char, Period), 4)+ '-' + RIGHT(Period, 2) + '-1', 102) <= @THE_DATE)                    
UNION ALL
SELECT     CAST(Census AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TheSum, Period           
FROM         [MANUAL].SMARTSOLVE_CENSUS                 
WHERE     (Period >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0) AND Period <= @THE_DATE) AND (PL In (Select distinct * FROM #tbl_PL))
))A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joel and Lamak pointed out you have an extra ) This is actually really easy to find if you use something like [Instant SQL formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) This will give the error

```
)(11,3) expected token:Unknown
)(11,3) expected token:
```

It also formats the SQL as below which makes it a little easier to follow.

```
SELECT @ALL_TOTAL = SUM(thesum) 
FROM   (SELECT CAST(reliability.census.census AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) AS thesum 
        FROM   reliability.census 
        WHERE  reliability.census.pl IN (SELECT DISTINCT * 
                                         FROM   #tbl_pl) 
               AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR, period), 4) + '-' + 
                     RIGHT( 
                     period, 2) 
                     + 
                     '-1' 
                     , 102) >= Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0) ) 
               AND ( CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR, period), 4)+ '-' + 
                     RIGHT( 
                     period, 2) + 
                     '-1', 
                     102) <= @THE_DATE ) 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT CAST(census AS DECIMAL(9, 2)) AS thesum, 
               period 
        FROM   [MANUAL].smartsolve_census 
        WHERE  ( period >= Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0) 
                 AND period <= @THE_DATE ) 
               AND ( pl IN (SELECT DISTINCT * 
                            FROM   #tbl_pl) ))a
```

Comment: +1 For recommending decent formatting. Make your life easier people. Format properly :)

Comment: Amen, it's amazing the difference it makes in being able to understand (and debug) a query

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have mis-matched parentheses, double check and make sure they all line up correctly. You have one more ")" at the end of that last select statement than you have ever being opened. That's a lot of nesting! Make sure everything matches up how you intended, or you may get unexpected results if your UNION gets applied at the wrong level or something.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your query correctly, you have two errors. The first is an extra ")"  on the last line, it should be:

```
WHERE     (Period >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @THE_DATE) - 5, 0) AND Period <= @THE_DATE) AND (PL In (Select distinct * FROM #tbl_PL))
) A
```

And, I think you also have more columns on your query after the `UNION ALL`, you are selecting `CAST(Census AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TheSum, Period` and on the first one you are selecting only one column: `CAST(RELIABILITY.Census.Census AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS TheSum`